# Paths to mysqldump on windows and linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, codeigniter, mysql

I begin to creating some php script that make MySQL backup of database using codeigniter framework. But, i have a problem: how to know paths to mysqldump on windows or linux, because I find that mysqldump work on windows only if add full directory address where is this placed for example "D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump" and in linux is enought "mysqldump" and then add parameters to connect to database.
Can you help me?

Comment: lookup some infos about `$PATH` (or `%PATH%` under win*) environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, add the path to mysqldump to the executable to your PATH environment variable.

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

You can then run mysqldump from any folder. Typically common tools are added the PATH variable by installers, but sometimes if you are installing a tool manually you need to add it yourself.

Your PHP code should not have to search the filesystem to find mysqldump.

Answer (score -1):

In Linux, you can run mysqldump with redirection, so that you can specify where the dump file is created, like so:

```
mysqldump -password database > /path/to/file
```

Comment: OP is concerned with the full path to the mysqldump executable, not to the output file.

Comment: You're right.  Reading the post a second time, I see that.  Perhaps using `locate`, the full path the the mysqldump executable can be found.